# list of traditional Chinese sorted/grouped by number of strokes

Tags: strokes, word-lists

I'm looking for a list of traditional Chinese sorted/grouped by number of strokes.

I have found some lists which contain around 500 characters. I'd like to have more, at least 2,000. Also, some lists are obviously a simple conversion from lists of simplified Chinese. Hence, the number of strokes are incorrect.

This is for sorting purpose. I found that Chinese version of Excel can sort by number of strokes. Unfortunately, I don't have it.

[It is strange to me that this question is closed because "questions asking for learning resources are off-topic." I'm asking for a resource, not a learning resource, and the answer given, which is in a dictionary, won't be obsolete for quite a long time. Anyway, just different definitions, I guess.]

Answer (score 1):

> lists which contain around 500 characters

you must be kidding  500 only?

try the 國語辭典, maintained by the ministry of education, taiwan; it’s under cc 3.0. you may download the excel file here:

https://language.moe.gov.tw/001/Upload/Files/site_content/M0001/respub/dict_reviseddict_download.html

the first excel file should suit your need, it contain 8000+ characters, with colume indicated the stroke number, and radical.

have fun :)

Comment: Got it. Thanks. The files are really useful. It has 12445 characters with pinyin and zhuyin, and radical. Too bad some are jpg files and don't display.

Comment: @joehua , most, if not all, jpg files are variants. the remaining characters should be enough for most purposes, imo 